# Checking and Unchecking a Checkbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am stuck with a simple checkbox on excel vba userform. I have the following code in its Click event:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Me.Label1.Caption = "Checked"
    Me.Label1.ForeColor = vbRed
End Sub
```

When I click the checkbox1 in userform, the Label's caption changes and forecolor too. But when I uncheck it, the label caption does't disappear. Where is my code wrong or am I firing the click event again?

Comment: You don't handle the state of the checkbox. You need an `if...else` block that queries the checkbox state and sets the `Caption` and `ForeColor` based on that state. Your current code says *Every time the checkbox is clicked, set `Caption = "Checked"` and the `ForeColor = vbRed`*. Why would you expect it to do anything other than what you told it to do?

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your comment. But unchecking "an already checked" checkbox is not a click event?

Comment: Yes, it's a click event. But you've told it to do the **same exact thing** every time it's clicked. If you want the `Caption` to change depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not, you need to do that in code. You're telling it **Do the same thing every time, no matter whether it's checked or not**. The code does exactly what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Label1.Caption = "Checked"
        Label1.ForeColor = vbRed
    Else
        Label1.Caption = "UnChecked"
        Label1.ForeColor = vbBlack
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

After you paint it red, it won't turn green unless you buy another pot of paint. Nor will it change the caption it has been given without another instruction. Try this code.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    Dim Cap As String                       ' = "" at this time

    With CheckBox1
        If .Value Then Cap = "checked"
        Me.Label1.Caption = Cap
        Me.Label1.ForeColor = IIf(.Value, vbRed, vbGreen)
    End With
End Sub
```

The code intentionally demonstrates 3 ways by which you might achieve the desired result. The smartest is the one which, at once, uses the least amount of code and is the easiest to read (for you).

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. You're not handing lhe case when it's not `If .Value`. It does nothing different with the `.Caption` than the code in the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your code Variatus. The code you posted did not work, so I added an If block:

Comment: @StarShines I wonder why the code worked for me but not for you. I'm on Excel 2013. "Adding an IF block" wouldn't be the correct solution. The whole thing can be done with one If .. Else or with two IIfs, depending upon your coding preference.

Comment: @Variatus I tried If else too, but following your code, I used If within With and End With, so now Its working. Like Ken pointed out, Unchecking an already checked Checkbox is not running any other code, so using .Value then and .Value = False is working.

Comment: @Ken White Your turn.Your initial comment is wrong. Please explain why and how my code doesn't change the label's caption and color.

Comment: My orignal comment is not wrong. Your code *still* does not correctly handle changes to the `.Caption` when the checked state of the CheckBox is toggled. Test it yourself - run your code, check the checkbox, and then uncheck the checkbox.. You'll see the mistake I've pointed out *twice now*. An incomplete answer is not an answer. Still your turn. :-)

Comment: This is beginning to get interesting, Ken. I tested my code repeatedly. It works. But our discussion shouldn't be about testing. You should be able to point me to the line of my code where it fails. Let me remind you - I'm sure you have that experience - if the inexplicable does happen it often happens because of an error in the testing procedure. I think you should check yours:- A UserForm, 1 CheckBox, 1 Label, and my code in the UF's code sheet.

Comment: I've pointed it out twice. Let's try a third time: `If .Value Then Cap = "checked"` **only** handles the case when  `.Value`. It does not change when `not .Value`. Does that make it more clear? Run your code, cyheck the checkbox, look at the value of the `.Caption` which will be `"checked"`. Uncheck the checkbox again, and look at the value of `.Caption` again. It's still `"checked"`.  Is the checkbox checked? No. Does that make it clear? Your answer is incomplete, as I've said now three times. Please don't make me repeat it again. Still your turn. :-)

Comment: Aah! The variable `Cap` is originally "" (as I pointed out). If `.Value Then Cap = "checked"` leaves the variable with its original value if Value = False. In the next line the variable `Cap` is assigned to the label's caption. It will be either "" or "checked", depending upon CheckBox1.Value. Therefore a change is forced on every run.

Comment: Aah! The solution you've posted is unclear, which is why we've been wasting time here. It's also why the poster provided a non-working self-answer, because your answer did not point out explicitly what it did. An edit to do so (rather than a somewhat vague comment) would fix that and make both our comments irrelevant. Let me know when you've done that, and I'll do my part in cleanup here. :-)

Comment: BTW, this whole discussion could have been avoided if you'd simply edited to change the `if .Value` for the `.Caption` to the same technique you used for the `.ForeColor`, which would both have been more clear and avoided the declaration of an unnecessary variable. :-)